# Object associated with a tableViewCell is sometimes nil

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a customTableViewCell that has a property of type Marker.  I use this object to bind the UI elements like UILabel for example.

I have a TableSection object that I basically just use for grouped table to help manage things better.  It looks like:

```
@interface TableSection : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;
```

In my cellForAtIndexPath method, I do this:

```
    TableSection *tableSection = [self.markersList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    Marker *m = (Marker *)[tableSection.array objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.marker = m;
```

I want to update this cell if information I grab from a web service has more information.

So I get the indexPath of the object in my tableview, then I try this:

```
- (void)updateIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath marker:(Marker *)marker {
    MarkerTableViewCell *cell = (MarkerTableViewCell *)[self.MarkersTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

For my first section of the tableView, `cell.marker` is what I expect it to be.  In other sections however, `cell.marker` is nil.  Is there a reason for this?  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How UITableView works is that it only contains the currently displayed cells, nothing more.  So if the cell you are trying to access is not in the view then you will get nothing (or possibly garbage since the cells are reused).

The only way I found to deal with this type of situation is the use the data array.  Instead of making the marker tied to the cell make the marker tied to your data array.  Then when your webservice gives you your updated information you find that marker in your array and update whatever you need.  That way, whether the cell is on screen or not, your data source will be updated.  If it is offscreen then the next time it comes onscreen the code will call cellForRowAtIndexPath and your data source will pass the updated information to it.

Long story short, your data source is the only place where all of the data can be found and the OS does not release it to conserve memory.